# Wi-Fi dropping intermittently on Dell XPS13 (2015) - cfg80211 dmesg warning and stack trace

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel, 15.10, broadcom

Every couple of minutes my Wi-Fi connection is dropping, and this is accompanied by a `dmesg` warning and stack trace like this:

```
[ 2680.040170] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 2680.040197] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 504 at /build/linux-AFqQDb/linux-4.2.0/net/wireless/sme.c:850 cfg80211_roamed+0x86/0xa0 [cfg80211]()
[ 2680.040198] Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep nvram msr evdi(OE) pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core v4l2_common btusb videodev media vboxdrv(OE) btrtl btbcm btinte
l bluetooth binfmt_misc iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables nls_iso8859_1 dell_laptop dcdbas hid_multitouch dell_wmi sparse_keymap snd_soc_rt286 snd_soc_rl6347a snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_
event intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel wl(POE) kvm snd_rawmidi crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul joydev dell_led snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic input_leds aesni_intel snd_hda_
intel snd_hda_codec aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul snd_hda_core glue_helper snd_hwdep ablk_helper cryptd
[ 2680.040229]  snd_seq serio_raw cfg80211 snd_pcm mei_me rtsx_pci_ms snd_seq_device memstick snd_timer mei snd lpc_ich shpchp soundcore int3403_thermal soc_button_array dw_dmac dw_dmac_core snd_soc_sst_acpi 8250_dw i2c_designware_platfor
m i2c_designware_core spi_pxa2xx_platform acpi_als int3402_thermal kfifo_buf processor_thermal_device int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad iosf_mbi tpm_crb intel_smartconnect mac_hid industrial
io drbg ansi_cprng dm_crypt parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 btrfs xor raid6_pq rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 psmouse i2c_algo_bit ahci drm_kms_helper libahci drm rtsx_pci wmi sdhci_acpi video sdhci i2c_hid hid
[ 2680.040268] CPU: 0 PID: 504 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P        W  OE   4.2.0-23-generic #28-Ubuntu
[ 2680.040270] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 13 9343/0TM99H, BIOS A07 11/11/2015
[ 2680.040271]  0000000000000000 000000001ccf4233 ffff8800d9f07da8 ffffffff817e94c9
[ 2680.040273]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffff8800d9f07de8 ffffffff8107b3d6
[ 2680.040274]  ffff8800d9a32c78 ffff8802150a9000 ffff880212b8c480 0000000000000099
[ 2680.040276] Call Trace:
[ 2680.040280]  [<ffffffff817e94c9>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
[ 2680.040283]  [<ffffffff8107b3d6>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[ 2680.040285]  [<ffffffff8107b50a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[ 2680.040292]  [<ffffffffc052b5d6>] cfg80211_roamed+0x86/0xa0 [cfg80211]
[ 2680.040321]  [<ffffffffc08e5965>] wl_notify_roaming_status+0xc5/0x140 [wl]
[ 2680.040342]  [<ffffffffc08e4fa4>] wl_event_handler+0x64/0x1e0 [wl]
[ 2680.040363]  [<ffffffffc08e4f40>] ? wl_notify_scan_status+0x320/0x320 [wl]
[ 2680.040365]  [<ffffffff8109a868>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
[ 2680.040367]  [<ffffffff8109a790>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1f0/0x1f0
[ 2680.040369]  [<ffffffff817f06df>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
[ 2680.040370]  [<ffffffff8109a790>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1f0/0x1f0
[ 2680.040371] ---[ end trace 400e3aed01e10c06 ]---
```

In many (but not all) cases, this is immediately followed by a bunch of errors reporting an incorrect mac address:

```
[ 2684.709095] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address, mac = 58:97:1e:91:44:71   profile =58:97:1e:91:44:7e
[ 2684.709157] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address, mac = 58:97:1e:91:44:71   profile =58:97:1e:91:44:7e
[ 2690.717559] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : Wrong Mac address, mac = 58:97:1e:91:44:71   profile =58:97:1e:91:44:7e
```

When this happens I have to disable and re-enable my Wi-Fi using network manager in order to force it to reconnect.

- As you can see from the stack trace, I'm using a Dell XPS13 9343 (2015) running the A07 version of the BIOS.
- I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 and kernel `4.2.0-23-generic`.
- My version of `bcmwl-kernel-source` is `6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu7`, installed from the standard `wily/restricted` repo.

I'm aware of [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1415880), but I'm not convinced that it's the same thing I'm seeing, since:

- The problem I'm seeing occurs after a clean boot rather than just a resume
- The issue was [supposedly fixed already](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1415880/comments/73) in Wily

I've also tried updating from the PPA mentioned [here](http://bartongeorge.net/2015/09/01/kernel-panics-when-switching-wireless-networks-xps-13-developer-edition-9343/), but this did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should have spent longer trawling through the comments on the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1415880) I mentioned in my question. In particular, [this comment from Rafael Tinoco](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1415880/comments/57) seems to explain the warnings I'm seeing in the kernel log:

> I'm not wireless expert but, after reading a bit and analysing your
>   syslog output:
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423445] Call Trace:
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423451] [<ffffffff817aeed7>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423453] [<ffffffff81074d8a>] warn_slowpath_common+0x8a/0xc0
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423455] [<ffffffff81074e7a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423462] [<ffffffffc04c5e09>] cfg80211_roamed+0x89/0x90 [cfg80211]
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423489] [<ffffffffc07aba0b>] wl_notify_roaming_status+0xcb/0x150 [wl]
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423508] [<ffffffffc07a876a>] wl_event_handler+0x6a/0x230 [wl]
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423526] [<ffffffffc07a8700>] ? wl_free_wdev.isra.23+0x80/0x80 [wl]
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423529] [<ffffffff81093802>] kthread+0xd2/0xf0
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423531] [<ffffffff81093730>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423533] [<ffffffff817b67d8>] ret_from_fork+0x58/0x90
> Aug 20 12:57:16 martin04 kernel: [ 9464.423535] [<ffffffff81093730>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1c0/0x1c0
> ```
>
> ---
>
> This only means that broadcom WL driver tried to warn kernel that it
>   roamed from one AP to another and new BSS could not be found (meaning
>   that the card could not get all its new BSS - peers, APs, etc).
>
> *** Try configuring the wireless adapter to use a SPECIFIC AP *** and check your wifi env for interferences that might be stepping into
>   broadcom's driver decisions on whether to roam or not -> This does not
>   mean a fix for WL is not needed, it only means we would have to wait
>   for Broadcom to come up with a new driver.

### Update

I eventually got fed up with the intermittent dropped connections, so I tried replacing the original Broadcom (BCM94352Z) WiFi card with an Intel 7625 (at the time of writing [these cost around £25 from Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Computers-Accessories/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7265-AC-2x2-M-2/B00U8IUTNM)).

[The installation was very simple](https://www.windowscentral.com/dell-xps-wifi-fix-upgrade-wireless), and the new card seems to be working flawlessly using the built-in `iwlwifi` kernel driver (you can go ahead and remove `bcmwl-kernel-source`, since it's no longer needed). Over a week of fairly solid use of use I haven't had a single dropped connection with the Intel card (whereas in the same location and with the same hub this used to happen roughly every 10-30 mins with the Broadcom part).

Comment: Having the same problem, was thinking it's time to just buy a working card, thank you for this answer!